# Possible to set permissions for running workflows?

Tags: workflow, permissions, user

Good morning,

I have a site in SP2010 that has several workflows set up.  They are started manually via buttons on the Actions ribbon.  Is there a way to only grant certain users permission to run certain workflows?

For example:  There is a User button that initiates a user workflow, and a Management button that initiates a Management workflow.  Can I set the user workflow so only users will be able to run it, and only management can run the management workflow?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How are you initiating the workflows? If its via code, then you can do the validation before invoking the workflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no workflow settings in the SharePoint web user interface to grant permissions to one set of users and not another set.  As Amal is suggesting, one option may be to validate users in the workflow itself. Another option may be to purchase a third party extension that handles this requirement.  Or, if you are able, you can code an extension yourself.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen.  I'm fairly new to SP and wrote the workflows in SP Designer.  I didn't even know there was a way to write the workflows using code.